# Runtime error when running my code

Tags: c, codeblocks

When I compile my C codes sometimes I get this error message.

> Mycode.exe has stopped working..
>   A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
>   Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution available.

My C code :

```
#include<stdio.h> 

main(){ 
    char a; 
    a="S"; 
    printf("%s",a); 
}
```

So what is the reason for this problem?
Syntax error, Runtime error or another reason?

Comment: Please share your code or ask something more specific.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
main(){
char a;
a="S";
printf("%s",a);
}

Comment: It means (a) you're not just compiling and linking your program; you're also running it. And (b) your program is invoking *undefined behaviour* that is fortunately causing early termination by the OS. The code you just posted does just that. That code suggests a [good book on the C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=1|3.4128) is a sound investment.

Comment: @WhozCraig So isn't there a way to compile my code ?

Comment: As I said, your code is compiling *and* running. It's just plain bad code that invokes undefined behavior. Thus the suggestion for a book on the language. (and that code belongs in *your question*; not in a comment down here. And for goodness sake, *turn up your warning levels on your compiler*.

Comment: @WhozCraig ok..Thank you for your help! :D

Comment: Please turn on/up compiler warnings! Your code should give 2 warnings, one for assignment of incompatible types (assigning a string to a char) and one for improper format code (printing a char with "%s").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke printf with `%s` it means that `printf` will start printing at the given address and end when a null terminator is reached, because you are giving printf a `char` and not a `pointer` to a `char`, it tries to use the value written in `a` to start printing from.

`a` is a char taking up a space of one Byte while an address is 8 Bytes in a 64 bit system, so basically printf takes the value in 'a' and the the next 7 Bytes(which are random '*garbage*') and tries to use it as an address to stop printing.

that is why it sometimes works as you said, sometimes those random addresses are fine to start printing from, but sometimes they are addresses that you are not authorized to access like areas of memory used by the OS or kernel.

to solve the problem you need to make `a` a `char *` and *not* a `char`, and assign it with a string.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{ 
  char a; 
  a='S'; 
  printf("%c",a);
  return 0;
 }
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: although your code fixes one compiler warning, it does not fix the code

Comment: Did not notice the double quotes until now. Fixed that as well.

Comment: but are you sure that was the intended code ? maybe @gayantha-akalanka wanted to print a string, and not a single character only.

Comment: @dvhh I'm going by the sample code he provided. He is using a character variable and not an array declared as char.

Comment: I want to print only a single character.so think @Govind Madhu your suggestion is ok..thank you very much guys!

Comment: Unfortunately what you have done is given him a fish as opposed to teach him to fish as `monkeyStix` did in the accepted answer. The point of SO is not to blindly answer a question but explain why your answer solves the problem.

Comment: @KevinDTimm It's ok.I followed both answers.But i have another question.@Govind Madhu@KevinDTimm  What happen if i use double quotes in a="S"? ( I got $ sign as the output)

Comment: @GayanthaAkalanka - that is covered in `monkeyStix` answer

Comment: @KevinDTimm Gotcha! Thank you..